# PHP regex to generate HTML

Tags: php, regex

I have the following problem. I want to create a preg_replace() function to replace, for example:

```
[div_row_392]...text...[/div]
```

to

```
<div class="row" id="392">...text...</div>
```

Comment: This is a handy site for testing https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thats a handy tool, thanks!

Comment: you mean this https://regex101.com/r/eM6iJ8/1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
$html = "[div_row_392]...text...[/div]";
$html = preg_replace('%\[(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)\](.*?)\[/(.*?)\]%sim', '<$1 class="$2" id="$3">$4</$5>', $html);
echo $html;
//<div class="row" id="392">...text...</div>
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/iAtl2v)